# cypress cucumber - How to identify the which feature file calling step definition?

Tags: javascript, cypress, bdd, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

My framework contain `common step definitions` which calls from different `feature` files. I want to set the `locators` base on the `step definition` calls from feature file.

For example below `Steps` calling  `step Definition` from common module.

```
A1.feature
Then I click on "Save" button

B2.feature
Then I click on "Save" button
```

**Common step definition**

```
const A1= require('../../../support/locators/A1-loc.cy')
const B2= require('../../../support/locators/B2-loc.cy')


Then ('I click on {string} button', (buttonName)=>{
    clickOnButton(getButtonLocator(fromButtonNameAndFeatureFileName)
})
```

I want to choose the different locators for `save` button base on different feature file.
Means if `A1.feature` file calls then point to `A1-loc.cy` and if `B2.feature` file calls then points to `B2-loc.cy`

I dont know how to identify the calling feature file?

I know, how to identify the calling file? And below functions works perfectly well for the same. But calling from feature file, No idea. Kindly help me..:

```
module.exports._getCallerFile=()=> {
   var filename;

   var _pst = Error.prepareStackTrace
   Error.prepareStackTrace = function (err, stack) { return stack; };
   try {
       var err = new Error();
       var callerfile;
       var currentfile;

       currentfile = err.stack.shift().getFileName();

       while (err.stack.length) {
           callerfile = err.stack.shift().getFileName();

           if(currentfile !== callerfile) {
               filename = callerfile;
               break;
           }
       }
   } catch (err) {}
   Error.prepareStackTrace = _pst;
     console.log(filename)
   return filename;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it will add more complexity if you need to reuse that action for a new feature tho. I think a simple implement `cy.contains(buttonName).click()` should solve it for both features. Why do you need to do it differently?

Comment: @ĐàoMinhHạt, Thanks for reply. But NO ``cy.contains(buttonName)`` will not work. Locator of ``save`` button is different may be partially or may be completely, that's we are maintaining in the separate locator file. YES , agreed this is adding little complexity in ``f/w`` but it worth to do that..If it make it success.

Answer (score 0):

Why shouldn't you try to use different step text identifying from which feature file it's called?
For example, "Then I click on "Save" button from A feature"

Comment: Thanks for reply. That's a thing, That is not my ``f/w`` requirement. Otherwise everything willbe very easy:).